# Counting observations and adding them to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the return og 108 mutual funds and over from 1987 to 2019. I want to count the number of observations in total (excluding NA) over the existence of the funds.

I have been able to get the kurtosis, skewness, etc using the following codes:

```
kurt <- apply(funds, 2, kurtosis, na.rm = TRUE)
skew <- apply(funds, 2, skewness, na.rm = TRUE)
max <- apply(funds, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE)
min <- apply(funds, 2, min, na.rm = TRUE)
sd <- apply(funds, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
m <- apply(funds, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Then trying to the same with the number of observations and not succeeding:

```
obs <- apply(funds, 2, count, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Getting this error: 
*Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"*

The first 10 lines from the data set is here (funds). It is much longer but this should be sufficiently illustrative. As you can see there are a lot of NA in the first lines. Number of observations here would result in 0, and if one looks at the fund "DK.NORGE" the number of observations in the first 10 lines would be 10.

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0090002245623988, 0.00232763847063611, 
0.0666744669374286, 0.0541982646590207, 0.0357777115456177, 0.0112375620619904, 
0.0517733147448458, 0.0553272554088993, 0.0964919466161833, -0.183504972082187, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.0132758821474321, 0.0246370824973443, 
0.0436835891381346, 0.0356472795497187, 0.000293052003410121, 
-0.0158201720510295, 0.0677617514139583, 0.0710647033479483, 
0.0996190340976313, -0.26700522906759, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0609178826615828, 0.0330911715918167, 
0.0246199591154059, 0.0387559218497211, -0.0219724959665873, 
0.00576292730999128, 0.0607497869923317, 0.0968700634555142, 
0.118662582078258, -0.149187455335955, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.00338009126246408, 
0.0625741902662371, -0.0197095435684648, 0.0235653235653237, 
-0.0205574774344905, 0.0211513478402079, 0.0440504114817319, 
0.0713605727123872, 0.122338724009241, -0.193811951737024, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0182819486204802, 0.052568368712947, 
0.0223478709564888, 0.0430931528662419, 0.00418444259680784, 
0.0149102804245731, 0.0891504229496138, 0.101929676995524, 0.0713342508037151, 
-0.184479046400599, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(10L, 108L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("AI.NORS2", "AI.AKSJN", "AB.AKSPR", "AI.AKTIV", "GA.KAPIT", 
    "GA.GAMB", "BF.HUMAN", "AB.NOPEN", "VL.AKNOR", "AI.NORGS", 
    "AI.NORG", "BF.NORGE", "AI.NORGI", "AI.VEKST", "AC.NWECA", 
    "AC.NEQCB", "AC.NWECD", "AC.NWECI", "NR.NORGE", "BF.NORG", 
    "CA.AKSJE", "CL.AKNOR", "FF.AKFOR", "FF.NOIII", "FF.NOAI2", 
    "FF.NORGE", "FF.NORII", "FF.VEKST", "DF.NORGE", "DF.VEKST", 
    "DK.PBNOR", "DK.NORGE", "DK.NORII", "DI.RINV", "DK.NORG3", 
    "DK.NORIV", "DK.NOIVR", "DK.NSEL1", "DK.NSEL2", "DK.NSEL3", 
    "DI.RVKST", "DI.SMB", "EK.NORGE", "NF.PLUSS", "FT.GNRTR", 
    "FT.NOFOK", "FF.BARNE", "FK.AKTI2", "FK.SPAR", "FV.NORGE", 
    "FV.TRNDR", "GA.OPPKJ", "GF.AKSJE", "GF.INVES", "SU.AKTIV", 
    "SU.GLNO", "SU.NORGE", "HF.NORGE", "HB.HNORG", "HO.NORGE", 
    "KF.IPA", "KL.AKSJE", "KL.AKSNO", "IS.NORGE", "IS.UTBYT", 
    "IS.UTBYI", "NF.AKSJE", "KF.AVKAS", "KF.BARNE", "KF.KAP", 
    "KF.KAPIT", "KF.KAIII", "KF.NOPLS", "KF.AKPEN", "KF.SMB", 
    "KF.SMBII", "KF.VEKST", "OD.NORGE", "OD.NORGA", "OD.NORGB", 
    "OD.NORGD", "OD.NORII", "OR.FIN30", "PO.AKTIV", "FO.AKSJE", 
    "FO.INDX", "PV.VEKST", "NF.RFAKS", "NF.RFPLU", "AI.SKAFS", 
    "SE.NORGE", "SK.HORIS", "SK.SMB", "SR.NORGA", "SR.NORGB", 
    "SP.INNLA", "SP.AKSJS", "SP.NORGE", "SP.NORGA", "SP.STNOP", 
    "SP.NORGI", "SP.NOINS", "SP.OPTIM", "SP.VEKST", "SP.VERDI", 
    "SP.STVEN", "TF.NORGE", "OD.VÅRAK")))
```

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is not the right function here. To count number of non-NA value in each column use `is.na` with `sum`.

```
obs <- apply(funds, 2, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```

However, a better option is `colSums` which can take input as complete dataframe or matrix.

```
colSums(!is.na(funds))
```